# php mysql updating in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables:

- Products containing IDProduct, IDCategory, Name
- Suppliers containing IDSupplier, SupplierName, Phone
- ProductSupplier containing IDProduct, IDSupplier, Price, Quantity

I want to update (edit) the following: IDCategory, Name(product), IDSupplier, Price, Quantity, but i'm not doing the UPDATE query right:

```
$query="UPDATE products P, 
               category C, 
               suppliers S, 
               productsupplier PS 
           SET P.IDCategory = '$idcategory', 
               P.Name = '$Name', 
               S.IDSupplier = '$idsupplier',  
               PS.Price = '$Price', 
               PS.Quantity = '$Quantity'
         WHERE ((IDProduct = '$idproduct') 
           AND (P.IDProdus = PF.IDProdus) 
           AND (PS.IDSupplier = S.IDSupplier ) 
           AND (P.IDCategory = C.IDCategory))");
```

How do i do this right? Thank you!

Comment: `PF.IDProdus` shouldn't it be `PS.IDProdus`? there is no PF table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,85813,85813#msg-85813 this thread should give you all the answers you need.  In essence you should be using a join.